# NodeJs how to display table structured in console

Tags: node.js

Is it possible without installing new package?

*Here i am using cli-table package..*
[image]

Any easy way to do it ?

Comment: Don't think there's any *easy* way to do it. Why not look into the `cli-table` source code see what it does?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can use [console.table()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table) API without installing any node module. *NodeJS Added in: v10.0.0, [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table#browser_compatibility)*

```js
const structDatas = [
    { handler: 'http', endpoint: 'http://localhost:3000/path', method: 'ALL' },
    { handler: 'event', endpoint: 'http://localhost:3000/event', method: 'POST' },
    { handler: 'GCS', endpoint: 'http://localhost:3000/GCS', method: 'POST' }
];
console.table(structDatas);
```

The stdout in terminal like this:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to remove first `index` column?

Comment: @Max I found your solution for you here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53653088/12283811

Comment: It overflows if column contains a lot of data... how to wrap data properly in that column?

Answer (score 8):

```
var values = [];
Array.forEach(function(b, i) {
    values.push(
    {
        'Symbol': b.a,
        'BID': b.b,
        'CONVERT1': b.c,
        'Buy': b.d,
        'Sell': b.e,
        'Convert2': b.f
    });
});
console.table(values);
```

Result Console

[image: Result Console]