# Array of objects to text based table node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I am querying a sql database and getting a result like

```
[
  { id: '626916199783071750', birthdays: '10/3' },
  { id: '797279656595947531', birthdays: '01/02' },
  { id: '548976894576849555', birthdays: '3/24' }
]
```

But it could have more columns or rows so like it could be something like this

```
[
  { id: '626916199783071750', username: 'whatever', idk: true },
  { id: '797279656595947531', username: 'thing', idk: false},
  { id: '7972656595947531', username: 'idk', idk: true },
  { id: '874596745986988596', username: 'cooldude', idk: false }
]
```

I want to make it into a table I send to the console, something like

```
+--------------------+----------+
| ID                 | Birthday |
+--------------------+----------+
| 626916199783071750 | 10/3     |
+--------------------+----------+
| 797279656595947531 | 01/02    |
+--------------------+----------+
| 548976894576849555 | 3/24     |
+--------------------+----------+
```

Where it adds the formatting and the correct amount of rows/columns. I would use a npm package but I cannot seem to find one that takes an array of objects and outputs a table.

Comment: Does `console.table(array)` work?

Comment: it logs it to the console, but what if I wanted to get the data console.table creates as a string so i could send it with a discord bot @Nick

Comment: Hmm this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63737829/can-i-get-the-string-value-of-console-table-in-nodejs

Answer (score 5):

There's a very handy built-in way of doing this (works on the browser as well) using `console.table` ([Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_table_tabulardata_properties)).

```js
console.table([{ a: 1, b: 'Y' }, { a: 'Z', b: 2 }]);

// ┌─────────┬─────┬─────┐
// │ (index) │  a  │  b  │
// ├─────────┼─────┼─────┤
// │    0    │  1  │ 'Y' │
// │    1    │ 'Z' │  2  │
// └─────────┴─────┴─────┘
```

You can even restrict which properties get printed out:

```js
console.table([{ a: 1, b: 'Y' }, { a: 'Z', b: 2 }], ['a']);

// ┌─────────┬─────┐
// │ (index) │  a  │
// ├─────────┼─────┤
// │    0    │  1  │
// │    1    │ 'Z' │
// └─────────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Works in both nodejs and in chrome both of which formatted the table nicely using ASCII and html table respectively. Learned something new today. And tons more stuff in console object to explore later. Thanks.

Comment: yep this is great! Is there a way to remove the (index) column possibly though?

Comment: @ColinFrankel I don't think so, unfortunately.

Comment: one last thing. Am I able to get this as a string I can send with a discord bot. if I do `const table = console.table(whatever)` I do not get it.

Comment: @ColinFrankel it seems possible according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67859384/9504406

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to use danfojs-node.
It provides you multiple options to format the table you're creating

```
const dfd = require("danfojs-node")

function getTableString(rows: any[]) {
    return String(new dfd.DataFrame(rows));
}

export {
    getTableString
}
`
```

Note: installing "danfojs-node" required you to add `skipLibCheck: true` in `tsconfig.js` in case you're using typescript. [Reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/setup#typescript)