# How do I convert an array of objects to tab separated string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have an array of objects similar to the below:

```
const data = [
{ "name": "Amsterdam", value: 40000, uniqueId: '2432g53122141' },
{ "name": "New York", value: 200000, uniqueId: '24322141' },
{ "name": "Mumbai", value: 5000, uniqueId: '9999' }
]
```

I want to convert it to the below format using tab separated strings with proper formatting/alignment similar to below.

This is needed to be a string as I will be sending this data to a third party form which accepts only text and no HTML data.

```
Name         Value      UniqueId
Amsterdam    40000      243253122141
New York     200000     24322141
Mumbai       5000       9999
```

How can I achieve the same with proper formatting so that there is no alignment issues as the length of data for each property can vary as can be seen above. Is there any package available?

Comment: Do you want it to be tab-separated or should it be fixed-width fields? They're not the same thing.

Comment: It seems that the OP needs fixed width fields based on the longest text in each field

Comment: @Barmar Yes I need fixed width based on text of longest field.Of course as I mentioned I do not want any HTML related solution as that would not be accepted the by the third party form

Comment: Maybe ```console.table(data, columns)``` helps you with printing the data (not tab seperated)

Comment: Loop through the array to get the maximum length of each field. Then loop through it again formatting into fields of the appropriate width.

Comment: @AG80 How are you going to capture that into a string so you can send it to the third-party form?

Comment: You only need to find the max string length of the `name` and `value` strings as the `uniqueId` is always at the end of the output string.

Comment: @Barmar Maybe this thread will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67859384/12165605

Answer (score 4):

- Loop through the array and collect the max length for each property in an object.
- Then loop through the array -> `padEnd` the values to the max length for that key -> `join` them with a `\t` get each row value. Loop the properties in the same order as `maxLength` object in case the properties are missing / or are in different order
- Then `join` each row with a `\n` to get the table body.
- Join the headers and the body with a `\n` to get the output.

This works for any number of properties, missing properties, properties in different order, null values

```js
const data = [
  { "name": "Amsterdam", value: 40000, uniqueId: '2432g53122141' },
  { "name": "New York", value: 200000, uniqueId: '24322141' },
  { "name": "Mumbai", value: 5000, uniqueId: '9999' }
]

const maxLength = {}

for (const o of data) {
  for (const key in o)
    maxLength[key] = Math.max(maxLength[key] ?? 0, String(o[key] ?? '').length)
}

console.log(maxLength)

const headers = Object.entries(maxLength)
                      .map(([k, length]) => k.padEnd(length))
                      .join("\t")

const rows = data.map(o =>
  Object.entries(maxLength)
        .map(([k, length]) => String(o[k] ?? '').padEnd(length))
        .join('\t')
).join('\n')

console.log( [headers, rows].join('\n') )
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```js
const data = [
  { "name": "Amsterdam", value: 40000, uniqueId: '2432g53122141' },
  { "name": "New York", value: 200000, uniqueId: '24322141' },
  { "name": "Mumbai", value: 5000, uniqueId: '9999' }
]
const header = Object.keys(data[0])
const rows  = [header, ...data.map(d => Object.values(d))]



const maxLength = Math.max(...rows.flat().map(s => s.toString().length))

const result = rows.map(d => d.map(s => s.toString().padEnd(maxLength, ' ')).join('\t')).join('\n')

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example of how you could do it. You could read all the attributes of the json and then try to generate the lines. In order to do the identation I took the largest string in the json and use it as an identation length

```js
function tabify(data) {
    var columns=new Set()
    //Get all the colums
    for(var index in data){
      for(var iKey in Object.keys(data[index]))
          columns.add(Object.keys(data[index])[iKey])
    }
    var maxLength = 0
    //Search maxLength
    for (var index in data) {
        columns.forEach((element) => {
            if (maxLength < element.length)
                maxLength = element.length
            if (maxLength < data[index][element].length)
                maxLength = data[index][element].length
        });
    }
    var outText = ""
    //Generate column line
    columns.forEach((element) => {
        outText += element
        outText += Array((maxLength - element.length) + 1).join(" ")
    });

    outText += "\n"

    //Generate the text formated
    for (var index in data) {
        columns.forEach((element) => {
            outText += data[index][element]
            outText += Array((maxLength - (data[index][element].toString()).length) + 1).join(" ")

        });
        outText += "\n"
    }
    return outText

}

let dataJson = [{
        "name": "Amsterdam",
        value: 40000,
        uniqueId: '2432g53122141'
    },
    {
        "name": "New York",
        value: 200000,
        uniqueId: '24322141'
    },
    {
        "name": "Mumbai",
        value: 5000,
        uniqueId: '9999'
    }
]
text = tabify(dataJson)

console.log(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code with lodash library

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
    
const data = [
   { name: "Amsterdam", value: 40000, uniqueId: '2432g53122141' },
   { name: "New York", value: 200000, uniqueId: '24322141' },
   { name: "Mumbai", value: 5000, uniqueId: '9999' }
];

const header = _.keys(data[0]);
const values = _.map(data, (iterator) => _.values(iterator));
let maxLength = _.max(_.concat(header, ...values).map(iterator => iterator.length));

let result = '';
result += header.map(x => _.padEnd(x, maxLength)).join('\t').concat('\n');
_.map(values, (iterator) => result += iterator.map(x => _.padEnd(x,maxLength)).join('\t').concat('\n'));

console.log(result.trim());
```